# How can Qt process communicate with normal Linux process?

Tags: qt, sockets

By UNIX domain socket?

By normal TCP/UDP socket?

In my xenomai layer, I have use xddp to generate one virtual port(/dev/rtp0), normal Linux process can access by open this port, and read/write the stream. But it seams difficult for Qt to access the port using QFile.

Comment: A process is a process is a process. There's no difference between them. A process running a Qt program, and process running some other program, they can communicate using whatever method you seem fit. Sockets? Pipes? Message queues? And any other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) method you can think of will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the UNIX domain socket, but there is some connection problem, so I doubt maybe my working direction is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> By UNIX domain socket?
>   By normal TCP/UDP socket?

the answer is: yes, both, why not?

Qt processes are normal processes, and they can do whatever other linux processes can do. You should be able to open a device file like you'd open it in any other process. Also note that no-one's *forcing* you to use `QFile`; you can use normal `fopen`/`fread`/`mmap`/`ioctl`.. whatever you do to interact with your `/dev/rtp0`, but I don't think there's anything stopping you from handling files as `QFile` and getting the low-level file descripter as soon as you need it from that class.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very familiar with Qt, I tried the QFile and QTextStream, when I opened the/dev/rtp0 port, but nothing is read from. Also I did not find many examples on this topic.

Comment: you're an embedded developer if you're dealing with Xenomai! I think you should be ready to work with Linux file handles if you want to communicate with a real-time system kernel interface. QFile has very extensive docs and is used in thousands of projects; I'm pretty sure you can find an example for its usage if you look a little harder.

Comment: Pretty sure, also, that a real-time system probably won't be exchanging information with you that would fit the "text stream" idea very well. but maybe I'm wrong. anyway, it seems you should break down your problems a little bit: Write a Linux program that successfully talks to your xddp device. That same program should work with Qt, too.

Comment: I was a project manager, but half a year ago I act as semi-developer(cause the shortage of developers in the team). I have successfully tested the xenomai process and normal Linux process yesterday, they can communicate with each other by unix domain socket.( xddp send string data to /dev/rtp0, then a regular Linux thread in the same process open the port and get the data,then send them out. I am not a senior developer, even not a junior one. But I learned fast. I started learn Linux this year, and I have tried yocto, compiled the kernel and xenomai, also tested can bus and so on.

Comment: Pretty sure, also, that a real-time system probably won't be exchanging information with you that would fit the "text stream" idea very well. but maybe I'm wrong. anyway, it seems you should break down your problems a little bit: Write a Linux program that successfully talks to your xddp device. That same program should work with Qt, too.

Comment: I read some QFile document, it says QFile does not emit some readyRead() signal, so it is not suitable for the UNIX device file. I will try QLocalServer and QLocalSocekt again tomorrow.

Comment: what? that doesn't make sense; the concept of Qt signals is totally orthogonal to the question whether a file handle works with a device file.

Comment: I tested with the exact program to a local file, for example "id_rsa.pub", the QFile works fine, and the data can be read out..., but with rtp0, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the QLocalServer, it works! The Qt process can send data to the xenomai process by the UNIX domain socket.